# Prove that for any Conservative Vector Field F, $\frac{dF_{i}}{dx_{j}} = \frac{dF_{j}}{dx_{i}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I don't even know where to start. Could someone walk me through this so I can actually understand how to get the answer?

If anyone knows a good source that could help me understand them better as well, that would be GREATLY appreciated. The full question goes as follows:

Given that $U \subset R^{n}$ and $F: U \rightarrow R^{n}$ is a vector field on $U$, if F is conservative, so that $F=\nabla f$ for some smooth $f: U \rightarrow R$, prove that $\frac{dF_{i}}{dx_{j}} = \frac{dF_{j}}{dx_{i}}$.

Comment: Hint: $F_i = \frac{df}{dx_i}$

Comment: This should follow directly from the definition of $F$ and [Clairaut's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives). As far as conservative vector fields go in general, it just means that the field is the gradient of some potential function, and this is useful because of the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integration. (which you'll probably go over at a later time if you haven't already)

Comment: This is a question-answer-site, @podiki, and this question is nothing but a problem statement, with the only context given, has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @podiki could you go further on what's wrong with the question, I would like to improve my questions because I have a tendency to get many down votes for bad questions.

Comment: Due to your comment earlier, that comment was deleted before you just posted your last comment.  No accusations.  Students miss classes for many reasons. This site is not the place to seek pity.

Comment: Start with this, @JamesE  [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.0747).  Thanks for asking.  Providing sufficient context doesn't require you "to show your work" (it's only one of many ways to show context); mainly it's about providing users with sufficient information as to one's course level, citing the source of the exercise, what specifically has one "stuck".  Information that allows us to take your level in math and address specific issues that are confusing you.